# Subclipse can't rename file (OS X)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I can't perform any Subversion operations on my Eclipse project as Subclipse can't rename a file. The error is:

```
Caused by: org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Cannot rename file '/Users/damianharvey/Sites/Odyssey3.5/OdysseyEDIJAXB/src/com/locuslive/edi/edifact/d95b/coreor/.svn/tmp/entries' to '/Users/damianharvey/Sites/Odyssey3.5/OdysseyEDIJAXB/src/com/locuslive/edi/edifact/d95b/coreor/.svn/entries'
at org.tigris.subversion.javahl.JavaHLObjectFactory.throwException(JavaHLObjectFactory.java:777)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.throwException(SVNClientImpl.java:1850)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.cleanup(SVNClientImpl.java:863)
at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.cleanup(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:1958)
... 8 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Cannot rename file '/Users/damianharvey/Sites/Odyssey3.5/OdysseyEDIJAXB/src/com/locuslive/edi/edifact/d95b/coreor/.svn/tmp/entries' to '/Users/damianharvey/Sites/Odyssey3.5/OdysseyEDIJAXB/src/com/locuslive/edi/edifact/d95b/coreor/.svn/entries'
```

I'm running OSX Snow Leopard, Eclipse 3.5, Subclipse 1.6.5.

It looks like a permissions problem. If I list the directories in the error I get:

```
drwxrwxrwx   8 damianharvey  staff   272 19 Nov 17:43 .
drwxrwxrwx  16 damianharvey  staff   544 21 Sep 14:53 ..
-r--r--r--   1 damianharvey  staff  2030 21 Sep 14:53 all-wcprops
-r--r--r--   1 damianharvey  staff  2313 21 Sep 14:53 entries
drwxrwxrwx   2 damianharvey  staff    68 21 Sep 14:53 prop-base
drwxrwxrwx   2 damianharvey  staff    68 21 Sep 14:53 props
drwxrwxrwx  15 damianharvey  staff   510 21 Sep 14:53 text-base
drwxrwxrwx   6 damianharvey  staff   204 19 Nov 17:19 tmp
```

So I assume that it's the read-only permissions that is preventing this. If I try to chmod this to a very broad 777:

```
sudo chmod 777 /Users/damianharvey/Sites/Odyssey3.5/OdysseyEDIJAXB/src/com/locuslive/edi/edifact/d95b/coreor/.svn/entries
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/damianharvey/Sites/Odyssey3.5/OdysseyEDIJAXB/src/com/locuslive/edi/edifact/d95b/coreor/.svn/entries: Operation not permitted
```

Any ideas? Would quite like to commit my code.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No worries. Aunty Google found it for me

```
chflags -R nouchg .
```

From the [comments here](http://markphip.blogspot.com/2007/02/subclipse-120-released.html):

> If you're changing workspaces on OS X
>   and you import an SVN-based project
>   into your new workspace, some of your
>   files may have the uchg flag set.
>   SubClipse/SVN will not be able to
>   update this project. You will get an
>   error:
>
> svn: Cannot rename file
>
> every time you try invoke svn. If you
>   issue:
>
> chflags -R nouchg .
>
> at the top-level of the project
>   directory this will clear these flags
>   and restore SVN function.

Comment: If I could vote you up once for every time I've used this answer, you might just give Jon Skeet a run for his money.

Comment: This does not solve my problem on mountain Lion, after the **chflgs** and a *svn cleanup*, I now get
'
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Sommes de contrôle de base différentes sur '/tos/trunk/org.talend.osgi.loader/JarLoaderClassLoadingHook.java' :
   attendu :  af3461bf428ac18216acbc562147c748
    obtenu :  f0e4692d230f90369828c79b004c67c0
svn: PUT of '/svn/!svn/wrk/123dc33b-4101-0010-89a6-2b00f149c3f7/tos/trunk/org.talend.osgi.loader/JarLoaderClassLoadingHook.java': 500 Internal Server Error (http://www.talendforge.org)
'